# How to set UITableViewCell height Dynamically with its content size to fit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios7

I want to set frame of content(i.e UILabel in cell) and cell dynamically without set frame of any UIControl programatically.

Comment: impossible, but good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborate your question with what have u done till now, if your asking for increase the height of the tableview cell you can use the below method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```